# Como agregar libreria itext a Java?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8.2, itext

Buenos dias comunidad,

Soy Principiante en el desarrollo de JAVA y debo importar libreria ITEXT.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pero creo la libreria y la agrego; pero al depurar sigue generando error ...

Debo importar

> ```
> import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
> import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
> import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
> import static com.itextpdf.text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
> import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
> import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
> import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
> import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
> import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
> import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
> import java.awt.Desktop;
> import java.io.File;
> import java.io.FileOutputStream;
> import java.io.IOException;
> import java.io.OutputStream;
> import java.util.Date;
> import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
> import javafx.event.Event;
> import javafx.scene.Node;
> import javafx.scene.Scene;
> import javafx.stage.Stage;
> import sistemanomina.Dialogs;
> ```

Alguien me Podria ayudar de alguna manera para poder solucionar este error, o Ayudar en el aprendizaje de Agregar Librerias . Gracias.

Comment: Para realizar esto debes crear un proyecto "Maven", agregar las dependencias y posteriormente agregar tus clases, agrego respuesta.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes descargar la útima versión de la [librería desde su página en github](https://github.com/itext/itext7/releases/latest).

Para agregar la librerá a netbeans una forma es:

1. abres el menú contextual sobre tu icono del librerías de tu proyecto y seleccionas agregar librería

   [image: Menú contextual]
2. Te aparecerá una lista de librerías para agregar, si no aparece la librería que necesitas da click en el botón para crear

   [image: dialogo para agregar librerías]
3. En nuestro caso se trata de una librería de clases así que seleccionamos esa opción y le ponemos un nombre inequívoco

   [image: dialogo de creación de nueva librería]
4. Damos click en el botón para agregar JAR o Directorios

   [image: dialogo para personalizar librerías]
5. Seleccionamos la ubicación en la carpeta de nuestro sistema operativo en que hayamos descomprimido los archivos

   [image: Selección de JARs]
6. Damos aceptar a todo y finalmente en el botón Add Library

Ahora en tu caso particular, no uses la última versión, pues si la descargas no compilará, la librería ha cambiado mucho.

Yo bajé la versión 5.4.0 y compiló sin problemas. [Maven central](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.itextpdf%20AND%20a:itextpdf) estaba abajo cuando la busqué así que la descargué desde java2s.

[image: aplicación funcionando]

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente elimina el import que no es necesario:

```
import static com.itextpdf.text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
```

#### [Configurar iText en Netbeans](https://developers.itextpdf.com/)

En el caso de Netbeans, debes crear un proyecto `Maven`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora selecciona el archivo `pom.xml` de tu proyecto ya que aquí es donde se agregarán las [dependencias necesarias](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/installing-itext-7):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrega las [**dependencías**](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/installing-itext-7) dentro de `<project>  <dependencies>    <dependency>` y realiza un **Build** de tu proyecto!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al realizar esto se descargarán los archivos .jar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora puedes agregar una clase a tu proyecto e importar las clases necesarias sin problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me ha ayudado mucho tu colaboracion ... No encuentro es una version de itext para agregar

Comment: @Jhonatancardona a que te refieres que no la encuentras? en la página indica que las versiones actuales son 5 y 7.

Comment: Te he votado negativo porque tu respuesta es totalmente incorrecta, y sezgada. El usuario está usando ant para construir su jar y tu le estás dando una respuesta que es para un proyecto maven, es por ello que no sabe como descargar el archivo. Puedes ver esto debido a que el icono de los proyectos es diferente.

Comment: Se escribe "sesgada". El usuario es principiante y desea aregar la library iText, mi respuesta da una opción de como realizarlo en Netbeans, de hecho era información de la página oficial a la cual llevaba el enlace que agreguė en mi respuesta y que se encontraba en 2018 cuando se realizó originalmente esta pregunta.